# Rounded or Circular Layout, is it possible?

Tags: android, layout

I have been looking for different ways to obtain a circular or rounded layout in android. I did find a good solution, android card view. 
By using

`card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"`

in xml it is possible to have a 50dp x 50dp circle layout additionally by adding

`cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"`

to xml would give me no borders or extras but just a plain circle view (happy with it). However **pre-Lolipop** it looks decently bad, I would like the layout to support **pre-Lolipop**. So I was just wondering if there is a way to have a rounded Layout with **pre-Lolipop** support(not an `ImageView` since the rounded/circular layout will be hosting child layouts).

Any help appreciated. Thank you;

Comment: you'll most likely have to create a custom view/layout as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Comment: looking into it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For drawing a circle, make your own drawable like this (red_circle.xml):

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="@dimen/none"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="2"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/Red" />
</shape>
```

Then set it as background of any layout or view :

```
<View android:background=@drawable/red_circle/>
```